# Is there a discrepancy between the overall quality of questions versus answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I don't know if this is a reasonable assumption, but my experience with UXSE is that questions are more likely to be asked by people with lower reputation scores while answers are more likely to be provided by people with higher reputation scores.

I am basing this assumption on the fact that UX designers with less experience are more likely to ask questions while more experienced UX designers will find it easier to answer questions.

If this is true (and we will need to run the query to check this), then would the quality of questions decrease over time?

Answer (score 2):

I tend to answer many more questions than I ask. It's *not* that I have *no* questions, but many questions have already been asked and answered. New users tend to not know the questions exist and don't bother searching for them.

When I do have a question that hasn't clearly already been asked and answered, I usually eventually answer it myself. Once I have an answer, there's no need for me to ask it, unless I feel it would be generally useful to others, in which case, I might consider posting both the question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Funny I was just thinking this as I scrolled through the list of questions and read the answers. I've been away from UX stack exchange for a while and it does feel like it has changed somewhat. There seem to be less experts involved.

Wondering if there are things we can do to attract them back?

Comment: Welcome back! I have been around for some time now and I think you do need new people coming in to help generate new ideas and conversations. However, I do think the platform favours people with more reputation (with good reason) but perhaps a weighted scoring system to people on their toes and do more to ask questions as well as answer them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not true. So experienced UX designers know so much that they have no questions?

I can't answer for UX.SE but I see it all the time in GD.SE: high-rep users asking great questions. Of course it's not daily, since the volume of lower rep users is much higher.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the fact that there would be a greater number of lower rep users, but lower rep doesn't necessarily mean that they are any less experienced. I guess it is really hard to say what a 'quality' question or answer is, but I do notice that the most voted questions are not necessarily the most complex or difficult ones to answer, just what people want to know the most (even if it is not a suitable question).